# R plot upper dendrogram based on k

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram, dendextend

I am clustering a distance matrix based on a 20,000 row x 169 column data set in R using hclust(). When I convert the cluster object to a dendrogram and plot the entire dendrogram, it is difficult to read because it is so large, even if I output it to a fairly large pdf.

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(abs(rnorm(3380000)), nrow = 20000))
mydist <- vegdist(df)
my.hc <- hclust(mydist, method = "average")
hcd <- as.dendrogram(my.hc)

pdf("hclust_plot.pdf", width = 40, height = 15)
plot(hcd)
dev.off()
```

I would like to specify the number of clusters (k) at which to truncate the dendrogram, then plot only the upper portion of the dendrogram above the k split points. I know I can plot the upper portion based on specifying a height (h) using the function cut().

```
pdf("hclust_plot2.pdf", width = 40, height = 15)
plot(cut(hcd, h = 0.99)$upper)
dev.off()
```

I also know I can use the dendextend package to color the dendrogram plot with the k groups.

```
library(dendextend)
pdf("hclust_plot3.pdf", width = 40, height = 15)
plot(color_branches(hcd, k = 44))
dev.off()
```

But for my data set, this dendrogram is too dense to even read which group is which color. Is there a way to plot only the upper portion of the dendrogram above the cut point by specifying k, not h? Or is there a way to get the h value for a dendrogram, given k?

Comment: Without delving too deep into this, this project might be of interest to you: https://github.com/thomasp85/ggraph

Comment: This SO question offers quite a bit for you, it seems, and references the dendenxtend package: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31124810/r-cut-dendrogram-into-groups-with-minimum-size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `heights_per_k.dendrogram` function from [the dendextend package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/), to get the heights for various k cuts.

For example:

```
## Not run: 
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests[1:4,]), "ave")
dend <- as.dendrogram(hc)

library(dendextend)
dend_h <- heights_per_k.dendrogram(dend)
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
plot(dend)
plot(dend, ylim = c(dend_h["3"], dend_h["1"]))
```

[image]

And in your case:

```
set.seed(2016-01-16)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(abs(rnorm(2*20000)), nrow = 20000))
mydist <- dist(df)
my.hc <- hclust(mydist, method = "average")
hcd <- as.dendrogram(my.hc)

library(dendextend)
library(dendextendRcpp)
dend_h <- heights_per_k.dendrogram(hcd) # (this can take some time)
plot(hcd, ylim = c(dend_h["43"], dend_h["1"]))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I know how to color the branches using color_branches() but do you know how I can label these branches so that I can read which group is which?

Comment: Use the "groupLabels = TRUE" parameter in color_branches

Comment: Thanks @Tal When I try 'd1 <- color_branches(hcd, k = 43, groupLabels = TRUE)', then 'plot(d1, ylim = c(dend_h["43"], dend_h["1"]))' some of the labels do not appear, I assume because they're lower than the lowest height plotted. Is there a way to control where those labels appear?